# How do you deal with density differences?

Tags: android, ios, maui

And I used to think CSS was bad.

[image]

DP, DPI, density, PPI, whatever it is - the higher it gets, everything starts to scale to the point where text just overflows, and my design starts to crumble.

I did the entire design based on 420 DP and I have the following controls predominantly in my UI code:

- ContentPage
- Grid
- Vertical Stack
- Label
- Image
- Button
- A switch
- A collectionview
- Entry
- Border

I don't know if these can be seen as "fancy" but I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible so MAUI wouldn't break.

FontSizes in my Labels are hardcoded, and this is where my problem begins.
Since there is MAUI does not dynamically scale font sizes based on available space, on higher density, I start getting overflows in text since they are meant to be say FontSize = 12 on 420 DP, but they look 28 on 560.

How many density values do I even need to support? Also this is only Android, we also have [iOS](https://www.ios-resolution.com/).
Is my only option to map `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density` values and make the same design dozens of times? I really doubt that is the way.
So, how do you solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add the code for your design, let's see where the problem actually stems from

Comment: I'm not sure how any code is supposed to help you.
Step 1) Drop a Label with a text and font size
Step 2) Go to Android Device Manager, Edit, change `hw.lcd.density`
Step 3) Observe different font sizes

You can also see you have less space to work with on higher density for things like grids.

Comment: Well you can't in the literal sense support every single density out there because I could just set an absurd density that does not even exist and ask you to support it and it won't work, When you want your font to scale-based on the screen-size and stuff you basically need to manually decide what values suit your design. I have been working with Mobile development for close to a decade now and that's how you do it be it any and all languages or frameworks

Comment: @FreakyAli how would you deal with something like this? https://imgur.com/Kq5Gvk8 I can provide some code if you like, but it's MauiReactor C#, something people would frown upon I suppose. It's made with a Grid and a few labels with set font sizes, width requests, etc. The middle (percentage) part is Auto width. Left side is 560 DP, right side (initial design) is 420 DP.

Comment: Could you please post some xaml code about this UI?